# How to get Vuex updated getters value in Vue custom middleware for permission check?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, user-permissions

I have loaded all permissions when the sidebar is loading after login and getters are updated. I can access all permissions from the sidebar component.
Now I want to access all permissions in my middleware. Is it possible? What to do?
Please give a suggestion.

Here is my permission store:

```
const state = {
    permissions: [],
    user: [],
  }
  const getters = {
    getPermissions: state => state.permissions,
    getUserInfo: state => state.user,
  }
  const actions = {
      userPermission({commit}, data) {          
        if (data != null) {
            axios.get("/api/auth/user", {params: { token: data.token}})
            .then(res => {
                const per = res.data.data.permissions;                
                commit("setPermissions", per);
                // console.log(res.data.data.permissions);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);            
            });
        }
      },
      userInfo({commit}, data) {          
        if (data != null) {
            axios.get("/api/auth/user", {params: { token: data.token}})
            .then(res => {
                const info = res.data.data.user;                
                commit("setUserInfo", info);
                // console.log(res.data.data.user);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);            
            });
        }
      },
  } 
  const mutations = {
    setPermissions(state, data) {
        state.permissions = data;
    },
    setUserInfo(state, data) {
        state.user = data;
    }
  }
  export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
  }
```

Here is the middleware function:

```
import store from '../store';
export default (to, from, next) => {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {        
        if (!hasPermissionsNeeded(to)) {
            next('admin/permission-denied');
        } else {
            next();
        }
        next();
    } else {
        next('/admin/session/login');
    }
};
function isAuthenticated() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("userInfo") != null && localStorage.getItem("userInfo").length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
        return false;
    }
};
function hasPermissionsNeeded(to) {
    var permissions = store.getters.getPermissions;
    if(permissions.includes(to.meta.permissions) || to.meta.permissions == '*') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Here is the router logic:

```
path: "/admin/country",
    component: () => import("./views/admin/country/country"),
    beforeEnter: authenticate,
    meta : {
      permissions: 'browse country'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you're dispatching the `userPermission` action to load the permissions, but I assume you're only dispatching it somewhere that only gets called after the middleware has run. So it looks like the permissions might not have been loaded by the time you're running the middleware. You might want to dispatch the permission in the middleware, wait for it to finish and only then check the permissions. For example:

```
export default (to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('userPermission').then(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated()) {
        ...
    })
```